# The repository is in queue for creation. Please check back here in a few minutes after tuleap update

Tags: git, tuleap

I updated `Tuleap` from version **7.0.99.10** to **7.5.99.72** via `yum` update command line.

After that I ran:

> /usr/lib/forgeupgrade/bin/forgeupgrade --config=/etc/codendi/forgeupgrade/config.ini update

But I still have an issue with the `git` plugin, it displays the following message:

> The repository is in queue for creation. Please check back here in a few minutes

`git` version is: **1.7.12.4**
`git` plugin version: **3.122**
`centos` OS version: **6.5**
`php` version: **5.3.3**

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of "System event monitor" in site admin

Comment: for information, I checked the code and I noticed that the function **isRepositoryCreated($repoPath)** always returns False even if the folder _/var/lib/tuleap/gitolite/repositories//<project.Name>/<repo.Name>.git/refs/heads_  exists

Comment: @vaceletm Here is it : [link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=307250Capturedu20141016180230.png)

Comment: Is 'codendiadm' user member of gitolite group on the system (id codendiadm) + what is selinux mode ?

Comment: Good shot. It was because 'codendiadm' user not present in gitolite group. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I post it for reference, it was because of `codendiadm` user was not part of `gitolite` group